# Bitwise operation positive number to negative

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Performance and optimisation debates aside.

I'm looking for a way in Javascript to take a number let it be 5 and using bitwise operations change it to -5.

The problem with flipping the bits is that 0 becomes 1 ergo ~5 becomes -6.

Is there a way to do this purely through bitwise ops? I feel that adding the 1 back on would negate the minor improvement that I may or may not gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negative number as an integer is the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). To flip the sign using two's complement you do like this:

> "To get the two's complement of a binary number, the bits are
>   inverted, or "flipped", by using the bitwise NOT operation; the value
>   of 1 is then added to the resulting value, ignoring the overflow which
>   occurs when taking the two's complement of 0."

In JavaScript that would be:

```
n = ~n + 1;
```

If you are looking for performance, that is not likely to be the fastest way. That would most likely be to use the operator specifically designed for that:

```
n = -n;
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: This can overflow, for example `n = 1 << 31`. I suggest `~(n - 1)` instead

Comment: @harold: It *should* overflow. The value of `1 << 31` is `-2147483648` and `~(-2147483648) + 1` is `2147483648`. If you use `~(-2147483648 - 1)` you get the incorrect result `-2147483648`.

Comment: @harold: If n = -2147483648, why would -n also be -2147483648?

Comment: @Guffa well this is integer context right, given that it's with bitwise stuff and all..

Answer (score 0):

It's not soo much faster. It does not make sense. When you need to negate the number noone can do it better than your CPU. http://jsperf.com/minus-vs-not

Comment: This is going to be used on data sets of 400,000 and upwards. Any performance gain would be nice. Regardless of how little the gain is I don't see why you wouldn't just take it?

Comment: The bitwise operator would not be faster than few percents and you are not able to negate the number by using only one. And when you use two Binary operators the advantage is gone. And 400000 is not too much for saving one tick. This isn't your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering how you would go back and forth between a negative & positive number (n) without using the + or - signs ...

```
n = ~n
add = 1
while add: 
     diff = add^n
     carry = (add&n)<<1
     add = carry
     n = diff
print(n)
```